# Constraint to the top of the main view without navigation bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, layout

Is it possible to set constraint to the top of the main view or UIScreen when there is a navigation bar on the main view in Swift? I need it because I when hide navigation bar and all that is under is moving top, because constraint is set to the navigation bar.

Comment: means you need to set constrain of label or button to the top of main view ?

Comment: @BadalShah yes, not to the bottom of the navigation bar, when navigation bar is on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , you can set vertical space from your control [Button or Label] to main view . Top layout guide. Just check image.

[image]

**Edit :-** With Navigationbar

[image]

Comment: t will work. When you have navigation bar. it doesn't matter with navigation bar. because you have set constrain with top to your Mainview. so , if navigation bar comes it will take margin from top of your main view.

Comment: If you will try to add vertical spacing to the top layout while you have navigation bar, constraint will be added to the bottom of the navigation bar. You can try.

Comment: If you add navigation bar it will be like is shown on your screenshot, but I want to prevent it, to become like on the first one when navigation bar is on the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104668/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-roberto).

Comment: One of the solutions we decided to do was to add view to the top and to add constraint to that view not to the navigation bar or main view

Answer (score 1):

If you want to the content to be dependent on the view not navigationbar.

You have to add top margin i.e vertical spacing to the view not the top layout guide

Comment: I understand this, so the question is how to do this

Comment: Click on the view below the navigation bar while adding top constraints select view from the drop-down